# Pledges table normalize

Tags: database, relational-database

I have this table and I don't know how to normalize.

1st table name, address, landline no., mobile no., e-mail ad, amount, and registration number https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2dDVLVHV4dU1yRFE/edit

and in the second table will be their monthly pledges. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B99TeByt30n2TVh4c1dmLTFYOWs/edit

Comment: That already is normalized

Comment: but what should i put like the foreign key, primary key

Answer (score 0):

```
PersonTable
  PersonId int primary key
  Name varchar(50)
  Addresss varchar(50)
  etc.

PledgeTable
  PledgeId int primary key,
  PersonId int foreign key references PersonTable(PersonId)
  PledgeDate datetime
  PledgeAmount decimal(10,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
You have to re engineer the whole idea.

I will give you a few concepts to understand what to do.

Keep in mind that we must NOT to have data duplicates.

So an array can be named Customer.
Customer can have a customer id column, named c_id for instance.
c_id must be defined as integer UNIQUE Auto_Increment NOT NULL

That means that it's an attribute that grants each customer its uniqueness.

A customer might have same name and same surname with another customer, but never same c_id.

Auto increment means that the first entry will be automatically numbered with c_id = 1, the next 2 etc etc.

Keep in mind that if you pass a record in the database using PHP, you enter null as value for c_id. Auto Incremet does the job then.

So you got a customer table and its first attribute that will be defined as the Primary key.

For example here is a small table:

CREATE TABLE customer

(c_id integer UNIQUE Auto_Increment NOT NULL,

c_name varchar(100),

c_surname varchar(100),

c_address varchar(100),

PRIMARY KEY (c_id)

);

You have to add all the attributes the customer has in the table.
That was just an example.

PRIMARY KEY (c_id) line in the end, 
sets c_id as the primary key that distinguishes each record as unique.

Then you got another table.
A Pledge table.

CREATE TABLE pledge

(pl_id integer UNIQUE Auto_Increment NOT NULL,

pl_date date,

pl_price double(9,2),

**pl_c_id integer**,

PRIMARY KEY (pl_id),

**FOREIGN KEY (pl_c_id) REFERENCES customer (c_id)**);

What is new here?

Line:
pl_c_id integer,

and line:
FOREIGN KEY (pl_c_id) REFERENCES customer (c_id)

What happens here, is that you create a column, that will contain an existing c_id!
That way, you make a reference to a customer, by using his/her UNIQUE c_id.

This is defined as integer, so it can fit the key. 
pl_c_id MUST be the same type as the primary key of the other table. Ok?

Also SQL will know what key we refer to, by reading the line:

FOREIGN KEY (pl_c_id) REFERENCES customer (c_id)

In plain English that means:

pl_c_id can be filled with values already declared in a Primary Key of another Table, named "customer" that uses as primary key the column named "c_id".

Got it?

Now you got the flexibility to use ANY date.

That is more normalized than what you got.
Usually a 3NF (Third Normal Form) you will be ok.

Oh! Not to mention that you can Google "3NF" or "Third Normal Form" and get nice results for your reference.
;)

Cheers.

Edit: Made this reply more simple to understand.